# this._appRef.registerChangeDetector is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have worked on the app with material2 and anular2. I have got this error "this._appRef.registerChangeDetector is not a function".

snackbar-material.html:

```
<button md-button (click)="openSnackBar()">Trigger Snackbar</button>
```

TS Function:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MdSnackBar} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
   templateUrl:'snackbar-material.html',
 })
export class SnackbarOverviewComponent{
 constructor(
    public snackBar: MdSnackBar) {}
openSnackBar() {
this.snackBar.open("Showing Snack", "Yayyy!");    
}
}
```

Error:

```
    EXCEPTION: Error in ./SnackbarOverviewComponent class SnackbarOverviewComponent - inline template:0:0 caused by: this._appRef.registerChangeDetector is not a function  vendor.bundle.js:61055:9
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: this._appRef.registerChangeDetector is not a function  vendor.bundle.js:61057:13
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:  vendor.bundle.js:61060:13
DomPortalHost.prototype.attachComponentPortal@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:66657:13
BasePortalHost.prototype.attach@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:35172:20
OverlayRef.prototype.attach@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:66238:28
MdSnackBar.prototype._attachSnackBarContainer@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:68168:28
MdSnackBar.prototype.openFromComponent@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:68122:33
MdSnackBar.prototype.open@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:68157:33
[653]/SnackbarOverviewComponent.prototype.openSnackBar@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:390:9
anonymous/View_SnackbarOverviewComponent0.prototype.handleEvent_0@/MaterialAppModule/SnackbarOverviewComponent/component.ngfactory.js:56:21
DebugAppView.prototype.eventHandler/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:86216:24
decoratePreventDefault/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:48265:53
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111220:21
NgZone.prototype.forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/this.inner<.onInvokeTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:31689:28
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111219:21
Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111109:28
ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111290:28
  vendor.bundle.js:61061:13
ERROR CONTEXT:  vendor.bundle.js:61064:13
Object { _view: Object, _nodeIndex: 0, _tplRow: 0, _tplCol: 0 }  vendor.bundle.js:61065:13
Error: Error in ./SnackbarOverviewComponent class SnackbarOverviewComponent - inline template:0:0 caused by: this._appRef.registerChangeDetector is not a function
```

Comment: You should define `selector` option in `component` metadata

Comment: I tried the selector option, but same result

Comment: try this in component `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default`

Comment: No, Its not work

Comment: Have you added the material module to your root module ?

Comment: yes, I have added that module

Comment: What version of Angular Material2 are you using? There's an issue on Github: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2107